# Subscribe Message file

Tags: ros, subscribe, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I want to subscribe data from .msg file. However the file has four other msgs inside. The format of the .msg file is:

```
Header header
geometry_msgs/Vector3 direction
geometry_msgs/Vector3 normal
geometry_msgs/Point palmpos
geometry_msgs/Vector3 ypr
```

Could you tell me how to read, for example, x,y,z coordinates inside geometry_msgs/Vector3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276564/subscribe-message-file/) by [Dornier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28451/dornier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a custom msg (**msg/mycustom.msg**) in my package called **mypkg**, created a publisher and 2 subscribers, one in *python*, another in *cpp*. You can see below:

**my_subscriber.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from mypkg.msg import mycustom

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("direction x: [" + str(data.direction.x) + "]")
    rospy.loginfo("direction y: [" + str(data.direction.y) + "]")
    rospy.loginfo("direction z: [" + str(data.direction.z) + "]")

def listener():
    
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("my_topic", mycustom, callback)
    
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

**cpp_subscriber.cpp**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "mypkg/mycustom.h"

void chatterCallback(const mypkg::mycustom::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("direction x: [%.2f]", msg->direction.x);
  ROS_INFO("direction y: [%.2f]", msg->direction.y);
  ROS_INFO("direction z: [%.2f]", msg->direction.z);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "cpp_subscriber");
  
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("my_topic", 1000, chatterCallback);
  
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

There's a video step-by-step showing how I did it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLfJZf9py0g

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2020-03-05**:
how about if the data is a array?